# email encryption for medical lab company

Tags: email, pdf, encryption

we need to encrypt the emails that contain PDFs that are coming from our laboratory management system to our clients. we do not have access to our clients machines. we dont want to issue everyone passwords because 1. they might forget it, 2. we dont want them to have to enter the password every time they view the PDF. is there a free or NOT free way to encyrpt these emails so that the client does not have to do anything to be able to open them?

is there a pdf tool that will allow for the receiving party to just enter the password ONCE and not have to do it at all after that>?

Comment: PDF files are about as secure as the average home. The lock on the door prevents the majority of people from entering, but it doesn't stop the thief from throwing a brick through the back window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using password-based PDF encryption is probably not secure, as the passwords would have to be very complex to avoid brute-forcing.

Instead, issue each user an SSL certificate and use S/MIME to encrypt each email.  The certificate can be installed into Thunderbird or the Windows store on the client machine.  If it's stored w/o a password, decrypting the email will be automatic.  Certificates can also be revoked this way.

Comment: we do not have access to cliebnts machines

Comment: You don't strictly need to access their machines.  You just need to send someone to their offices with a briefcase handcuffed to her wrist containing the certificates.

Comment: You're going to need to put *something* on the client machine.  In order to do symmetric encryption you need a shared secret.  Operative term "shared".  Meaning both of you have it.  In order to do asymmetric encryption, you still need a key on both ends.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a better question for Server Fault or Super User, but PGP is still an pretty easy way to encrypt emails.

Answer (score 1):

A roundabout route would be to create a web app that hosted the PDFs, and email them the link to the PDF.  Then you can do what you want with the security on the site, depending on how secure you need it to be.

It could range from as simple as something known only to them (lab ID number followed by user ID number), all the way through to something more complex (and secure) such as a password force-changed on a regular basis.

Plus, that brings the exercise firmly back into the realm of stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

You might try [PDF Postman for Outlook](http://www.encryptomatic.com/pdfpostman). It creates encrypted PDF emails and file attachments from your Outlook email, making that process easier.

on the recipient's end, it is possible to remove password encryption from a PDF that has been decrypted.  In PDF X-Change viewer (my pdf viewer of choice),  after the PDF is decrypted, I would go to File > Document Properites and change the Security Method to "No Security."  Now save a copy.